# Which one is syntactic suger for Integer i =  123;?

Tags: java

Is `Integer i  = 123;` syntactic sugar for `Integer i =  new Integer(123);` or `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(123);`?How can I prove it?Give me a favour?

Comment: I will tell you the truth. That is not a good title.

Comment: @anubhava OP is asking about how to PROVE it, not how to read about it. Is there any way to demonstrate it empirically?

Comment: This isn't "too localized". It is, however, a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Integer i = 123; syntactic sugar for Integer i = Integer.valueOf(123);

How to prove?

```
enter code here
```

first, write a class like this:

```
public class IntegerTest {  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = 123;
}
}
```

complie it:

```
javac IntegerTest.java
```

view generated bytecode:

```
javap -verbose IntegerTest
```

we will get:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);


Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=2, Args_size=1
   0:   bipush  123
   2:   invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Int
eger;
   5:   astore_1
   6:   return
  LineNumberTable:
   line 4: 0
   line 5: 6
```

notice this line:

```
invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer
```

java.lang.Integer.valueOf() method is invoked!

Comment: You are very cool! But I can't understand the bytecode.What should I do for understanding the bytecode?